Changing aesthetics in humapr
recently I have been using humapr package in R in order to plot a body heatmap that represents the impact of a disease on diferent bodyparts. The package is based in ggplot2, using almost the same code structure. In my case, I was looking for change the labels to show summary statistics instead of frequencies, and using argument stat = "identity" doesn't make the desired change. This is the code I used:
library(tidyverse)
library(humapr)
set.seed(1)
    body_data <- data.frame(
      loc = rep(c(
        "Upper extremities", "Lower extremities","Trunk", "Head & neck"
      ), times = 2),
      side = rep(c("left", "right"), each = 4),
      gender = rep(c("male", "female"), each = 4),
      year = runif(8)
    )
    humap() +
      geom_body(aes(loc = loc, side = side, fill = year ), annotate = "all",
                data = body_data, combine =
                  list(
                    `Upper extremities` = c("arm", "forearm", "hand"),
                    `Lower extremities` = c("thigh", "leg", "foot"),
                    `Trunk` = c("abdomen", "chest"),
                    `Head & neck` = c("head", "neck")
                  ), stat = "identity"
      ) 

And this is the output of that code:

What Im looking for is to change the actual values (0 and 1, and that weird %) for the ones in year variable, with exactly 2 decimals. It's a bit outdated package but, at the moment, It is the one that better fulfills my needs.

You could turn off the humapr annotation, i.e. annotate = NA, then add a different ggplot (or extension) aesthetic, e.g. geom_table():
library(tidyverse)
library(humapr)
library(ggpp)

set.seed(1)
body_data <- data.frame(
  loc = rep(c(
    "Upper extremities", "Lower extremities","Trunk", "Head & neck"
  ), times = 2),
  side = rep(c("left", "right"), each = 4),
  gender = rep(c("male", "female"), each = 4),
  year = runif(8)
)

tb <- body_data |> 
  select(loc, side, year) |> 
  mutate(year = round(year, 2))

df <- tibble(x = 1, y = 0.9, tb = list(tb))

humap() +
  geom_body(aes(loc = loc, side = side, fill = year), annotate = NA,
            data = body_data, combine =
              list(
                `Upper extremities` = c("arm", "forearm", "hand"),
                `Lower extremities` = c("thigh", "leg", "foot"),
                `Trunk` = c("abdomen", "chest"),
                `Head & neck` = c("head", "neck")
              ), stat = "identity"
  ) +
  geom_table(aes(x = x, y = y, label = tb), data = df)


Created on 2024-04-05 with reprex v2.1.0

Hi Carl, thanks for your answer! I would like something more similar to the first case (labeling directly the body parts instead of external table).

Your best bet might be to raise an issue here and see if they respond?
